# Angular json encoded array to PHP format

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

The server on php expect from client JS array in this format:

```
"['id' => ['users'=>[] ]]"
```

in Angular i have id :

```
var id = '3534534543535';
```

how i can convert my id to PHP expected format???

Comment: Change it to an object like your php expects: var id = {users: '3534534543535'}. When you post id, it will be converted to proper json and when you use json_decode in php it will be in the proper format for you to work with it as a php object.

Comment: Thank you, but how i can get array from this? I need to send array on server.

Comment: id = 'id={"users":["3534534543535"]}'; That's work, but syntax incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this format:

```
var response = { id: { users: ['3534534543535'] } };
```

Then post it to your server as you were, probably something like:

```
$http.post('someurl.com', $.param({data: response}))
    .success(function(resp) { 
        /* ... */ 
    });
```

Then on your server:

```
echo json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
```